# Pulling Comments from MYSQL database using Php Cause unexpected JSON results

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am using a PHP script to pull comments from my database to populate an app. How the database is set up is any secondary comments, ie replies to comments, will have a reply_id. The issue im seeing is all comments, regarless of replies, are seeing the same replies as the one comment that has it. I tried deleting the array with the secondary comments in it, but to no avail. Could someone point out where I failed to seperate the values?

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    $memory_id=$_POST['memory_id'];
        $query ="Select * FROM  comment WHERE memory_id= '$memory_id' and reply_id=''";
        $dbquery = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $query2= "Select * FROM  comment WHERE memory_id='$memory_id' and reply_id='$comment_id'";
    if($dbquery){
        $result = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbquery))
        {
            $temp_array= array();
            unset($temp_array['replys']);
            $temp_array['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
             $temp_array['comment_id']=$row['comment_id'];
             $temp_array['text']=$row['comment'];
             $comment_id= $row['comment_id'];
             $temp_array['replys']=array();
             $dbquery2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
                if($dbquery2){
                 while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($dbquery2)){
                  $temp_array['replys'][]=array(
                  'user_id'=>$row2['user_id'],
                  'comment_id'=>$row2['comment_id'],
                  'text'=>$row2['comment']);
                 }//Feeds comments
             array_push($result, $temp_array);
             }
     }//pulls initial command 
       echo json_encode($result);
    }
    else
    {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "No memory FOund";
            echo json_encode($response);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is being executed with `$memory_id` having the value of `$_POST['memory_id']`. An easy solution is to move the `$query2` line below `$memory_id = $row['memory_id']`, that way the second query will be executed with the correct `memory_id` value.

**EDIT**
A better solution is to prepare your queries instead. Check the [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) function.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for the help and insight.